# I'm trying to play a video on a website I'm making. It will play in HTML5, but doesn't play using ASP.net. What am I missing?

Tags: asp.net

I've created code for HTML5 identical to that which I use in ASP, but the video never loads. It's like it's never found; there's just an empty video player sitting there on the scree. The same code works just fine in HTML. Here's the code I used for both (minus the asp tags in HTML):

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <video width="960" controls>
        <source src="Printer_network_config.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    </asp:Content>
```

Any ideas why the video doesn't play? Nothing I've found online helps; it's all just proper syntax and what tags to use.

I've viewed the page source in the browser, but it apparently can't find the video file;

*Resolution:* I neglected to properly close the source tag. Small and simple things.

Comment: Check the HTML emitted from the ASP.NET page (View/Source in the browser).  Compare it with your working HTML.

Comment: Did the `Printer_network_config.mp4` found on the same dir with this page ?

Comment: **Robert--** I'm a moron and didn't close my source tag, but you got me looking there with the page source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to close ALL tags. Especially the source tag.